# ubuntu-16.04-desktop Installation

Tags: software-installation

I have downloaded `ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso` and i need to install Ubuntu 16.04 desktop` on my laptop. My processor is Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3517U CPU @ 1.90GHz 2.40Ghz.
Is it possible to install this OS on my laptop?

Comment: check this link may help you https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

Comment: Backup Windows, and use Windows to shrink the NTFS partition. Reboot immediately so it can run chkdsk. Then be sure to boot installer in UEFI boot mode. Shows install with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Something Else or manual Install
http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/dual-boot-windows-8-ubuntu.html
Also shows Windows 8 screens or similar to Windows 10
http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why it shouldn't work just fine. To be on the safe side, try running a live session first and see how things go before proceeding with the installation.